# Java how to add these elements to int array using loop then return the array

Tags: java, arrays

I can't seem to figure out how I'm not getting the right output

```
int [] f = {1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1};
int [] b = {0,3,3};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hide(f,b)));

    // declare int array that will be returned by following method
int [] hiddenAt = {};

public static int [] hide(int [] front, int [] back) {
    if (back.length > front.length) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < (front.length - 1); x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < (back.length - 1); y++){
            int temp = front[y];

            if (front[y] - back[y] <= front[y] && front[y] - back[y]  >= 0 ) {
                hiddenAt.add(temp);
            }

        }
    }
    return hiddenAt;
}
```

I'm trying to compare the first and second array so that I find where the second array will fit into the first array without going over the max on the first so...

First time through the loops:
0 compares with 1, 2 compares with 3, then 3 with three (This doesn't work)
Second time it shifts positions:
0 with 2, 2 with 3, 3 with 4 (works)
third time:
0 with 3, 3 with 4, then 3 with 5 (works again)

Then for every position in the array it works an array is return with those values so in this example is would be front[1], front[2], front[3] so on such that the returned array looks like {1, 2, 3 ... }

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. What do you mean by `2nd array fit in 1st array`?

Comment: THis doesn't look like Java. You can't 'add' to an array in Java.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to input the values needed into the hiddenAt array. So, I'm not sure what the 'add' is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop needs to look like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < (front.length); x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < (back.length); y++){
        int temp = front[y];

        if (front[x] - back[y] <= front[x] && front[x] - back[y]  >= 0 ) {
            hiddenAt.add(temp);
        }

    }
}
```

Also you need to take out the -1 from the length, for example the length of front is 10. So the array goes from 0 - 9 starting at 0, that is 10 different values the -1 took you from 0 - 8 and that lost you values. You can keep the -1 if you do <= instead of <.

write on a piece of paper and point to each spot in the arrays as you step through it and literally see what is happening if this doesn't get your result.

Answer (score 4):

Your are not using x so the outer loop is not doing its job. Use front[x] and back[y]

Comment: For every time I use them within the loops?